# Constructing an Account SAS (Shared Access Signature)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to generate Account SAS token:
[MSDN DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt584140.aspx)

When I am trying to use generated token, I get following:

> `AuthenticationFailed`
>       Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:89959111-0001-00c8-24d1-e0515b000000
>   Time:2016-07-18T08:49:00.8383767Z
>       Signature did not match. String to sign used was [accountName]
>   rl
>   b
>   sc
>   2017-01-01
>   2015-04-05

Here are my code:

```
        var signedVersion = "2015-04-05";
        var signedServices = "b";
        var signedResourceTypes = "sc";
        var signedPermission = "rl";
        var signedExpiry = "2017-01-01";

        var stringToSign =
            accountName + "\n" +
            signedPermission + "\n" +
            signedServices + "\n" +
            signedResourceTypes + "\n" +
            signedExpiry + "\n" +
            signedVersion + "\n"
            ;

        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accountKey);

        byte[] hash;
        using (var mac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            var stringToSignBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
            hash = mac.ComputeHash(stringToSignBytes);
        }

        var str = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        var sig = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str);

        var url = $"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&sv={signedVersion}&ss={signedServices}&srt={signedResourceTypes}&sp={signedPermission}&se={signedExpiry}&sig={sig}";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a few issues with the code:

First, to convert account key into byte array you would need to use `Convert.FromBase64String(accountKey)` instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accountKey);`.

Next, even if you're not using start time, signed protocol and signed IP addresses, you would need to include them in your `stringToSign`.

Once you do these things, the code should work. Based on these, I have included the modified code below. I tested it for listing containers in my storage account and it works.

```
    static void AccountSas()
    {
        var signedVersion = "2015-04-05";
        var signedServices = "b";
        var signedResourceTypes = "sc";
        var signedPermission = "rl";
        var signedExpiry = "2017-01-01";
        var signedStart = "";
        var signedIP = "";
        var signedProtocol = "";
        var stringToSign =
            accountName + "\n" +
            signedPermission + "\n" +
            signedServices + "\n" +
            signedResourceTypes + "\n" +
            signedStart + "\n" +
            signedExpiry + "\n" +
            signedIP + "\n" +
            signedProtocol + "\n" +
            signedVersion + "\n"
            ;

        var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(accountKey);

        byte[] hash;
        using (var mac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            var stringToSignBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
            hash = mac.ComputeHash(stringToSignBytes);
        }

        var str = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        var sig = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str);
        var url = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&sv={1}&ss={2}&srt={3}&sp={4}&se={5}&sig={6}", accountName, signedVersion, signedServices, signedResourceTypes, signedPermission, signedExpiry, sig);
    }
```

Comment: This one worked wonderful. So, even if field is optional, empty line is required in the stringToSign... Thank you for your help!